# $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] returning server's public ip and not client's

Tags: php, server

Actually, I have a problem which is `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` returning the server's public IP instead of client public IP as expected. I don't use any proxy so its not the case for sure.

```
<?php
$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
?>
```

Here is the output of $_SERVER:

```
[SERVER_NAME] => server public ip 
[SERVER_ADDR] => server local ip 
[SERVER_PORT] => 80 
[REMOTE_ADDR] => server public ip 
[DOCUMENT_ROOT] => root dir 
[REQUEST_SCHEME] => http 
[CONTEXT_PREFIX] => 
[CONTEXT_DOCUMENT_ROOT] => root dir 
[SERVER_ADMIN] => postmaster@localhost 
[SCRIPT_FILENAME] => root dir/file.php
```

Comment: There is probably a (local) proxy in front of the "To PHP passing"-webserver, do you manage the server? If not, contact the server administrator.

Comment: Try this code `echo "<pre>" . print_r($_SERVER, true) . "</pre>"`. You will get all the information about `$_SERVER` superglobal array. Check for `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR` to see if it exists.

Comment: i have the server here in my house. @Perumal93, no HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR doesn't exist.

Comment: There might be a proxy set. You need to make sure if `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR` is set in `$_SERVER`.

Comment: How are you accessing the server? Via local IP or what? Is it on the same machine as your computer?

Comment: Did you try this code `echo "<pre>" . print_r($_SERVER, true) . "</pre>"` to see if there is a IP address that you're expecting it should be?

Comment: @Qirel , i am accessing through public ip with dns from noip.com and i port forward the 80 port to the server's local ip through router config

Comment: Right, so since you're accessing it like that, you go from your house -> DNS server -> your house. So the origin and destination is the same IP, so there's nothing out of the ordinary here.

Comment: it has seperate router and connection than my ip. its in same house but different connection. even different router.

Comment: So you have two IPs in your house..?

Comment: yes 2 connections 2 routers hence 2 ips

Comment: i use xampp btw

Comment: If you actually have two different IPs delivered from your ISP to your house, then it's a configuration issue in your local routing (and that DNS for the matter). If you don't actually have two IPs, having two routers won't make it so. ;-)

Comment: i have 2 ips so the server has its own connection with different ip than the computer i surf the net with but no idea what local routing issue or dns issue could it be? i would like to know, plz. all i did i forward the 80 port to the local ip machine ip and that's it and dns just redirect to the public ip and that's it. also tried to access the page with direct ip (without dns and gave me same server's ip).

Comment: still waiting for answer guys. i hope u don't leave me like this